# PagedList a List of objects in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I installed the PagedList.MVC Nugget package and I'm trying to make a PagedList from a list, List<MyProject.ViewModel.AddProducts>ProductsList

**In my View:**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.ViewModel.AddProductsViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
    
                stuff here

                    <table class="table" align="left" style="padding-left:15px">
                        <tr>
                            
                            <th>
                                Product
                            </th>
                           
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                                                     
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
                                </td>
                               
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                    Página: @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de: @Model.PageCount
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new
                    {
                        page,
                        sortOrder =
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort,
                        currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
                    }))
```

**My controller:**

```
 public ActionResult NewSale(int? page=null)
        {
            page = (page ?? 1);
            var productspl = db.Products
              .Include(p => p.Category)
              .Include(p => p.Color).OrderBy(p => p.Description).ToPagedList((int)page, 8);           
            var saleViewModel = new AddProductsViewModel
            { 
                ProductsList = productospl,
            };
            return View(saleViewModel);
        }
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public class AddProductsViewModel
    {
          stuff
        

        public List<Productos> ListaProductos { get; set; }
     }          
}
```

The problem is that I can't access the ProductsList without changing this

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.ViewModel.AddProductsViewModel>
```

Is there a way?

Comment: You should use a wrapper viewmodel to hold the pagedlist as a property, then use that VM as the model in the view. This way you're not limiting yourself

Comment: Would you give me a code example? I think I get the idea but can't really picture it rn @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class ProductsPageViewModel() 
{
    public PagedList.IPagedList<MyProject.ViewModel.AddProductsViewModel> AddProductsPagedList { get; set; }
    // other properties/methods for your view go here...    
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model ProductsPageViewModel

// other HTML here....

Página: @(Model.AddProductsPagedList.PageCount < Model.AddProductsPagedList.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.AddProductsPagedList.PageNumber) de: @Model.AddProductsPagedList.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.AddProductsPagedList, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
    page,
    sortOrder =
    ViewBag.CurrentSort,
    currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
}))
```

Comment: I did this exactly and it throws a null exception when it gets here: "Página: @(Model.AddProductsPagedList.PageCount" in the view

Comment: Your `AddProductsPagedList` might be null. Are you setting it correctly in the controller? Debug and step through the code that sets it to see if it's null

Comment: I use LINQ to get .ToPagedList items in a variable to give value to a generic list<products>  inside my AddProductsViewModel, but don't know how to give value to AddProductsPagedList. (sorry about my english, I hope I can explain myself well, maybe we can contact so I show you some code)

Comment: Are you trying to add to the list on this same page? You'd want to do that on a different page, but have an [Add] button on this page

Comment: Come on over to MVC chat room and we'll talk more

Comment: I found the mistake. Just went to my List<Products> ProductsList and changed it for PagedList.IPagedList<Products> ProductsPagedList. It was it. You were of much help, thank you very much Alex. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, @BautistaGonzálezCarpani. Glad it's working for you

Comment: would you mind starting a chat room with me so I can ask you something I'm struggling with? @Alex

Answer (score 1):

In my ViewModel:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public class AddProductsViewModel
    {
          stuff
        

        public List<Productos> ProductsList { get; set; }
     }          
}
```

Changed this:

```
 public List<Productos> ProductsList { get; set; }
```

To:

```
 public PagedList.IPagedList<Productos> ProductsList { get; set; }
```

I want to thank the user **Alex** for helping me get to this answer and also helping me with other issues before.